# Javascript command activated via drop down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm new to using Javascript, and I need help with a project I'm working on. I know this issue is likely extremely simple, but Javascript isn't my strong point and I cannot seem to find what I'm looking for on my own.

The issue I'm having is that I need to change what's being rendered in a 3D model based on options available in a drop down menu. I just managed to get the drop down menu to change the material, but I need to figure out how to make it work with multiple materials off of the same drop down menu.

Here is what I have now:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="variant-option" id="js-mat-sel">
  <div class="variant-option-title">Finish: </div>
  <select data-variant-option-name="Finish">
    <option value="none">Select Finish</option>
    <option value="Silver" id="silver">Silver</option>
    <option value="Brass" id="brass">Brass</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
 $( "#js-mat-sel" ).bind( "change", function matchange(){
   lapi.applyMaterialToMeshByName( "Silver 1", "Group28884");
 });
```

Currently, as is, the script changes from the base material to "Silver 1" when any option on the drop down menu is selected. I'd like it to display the material "Gold 1" when I select "Brass" on the Drop Down menu, and only display "Silver 1" when I select "Silver" from the drop down.

Additionally, it should be noted that I'm using a derivative of an [existing API for the 3D rendering company, Lagoa](https://github.com/lagoa/API-Samples/blob/master/docs/lagoa_api.js.html).

[Edit:]

So, I know what I'm doing wrong here, I just don't know how to do what I want correctly.

It should also be noted that I'm getting "Gold 1" and "Silver 1" from an older form of the code that did what I was looking for via multiple CSS made buttons. Below is the code that worked. However, the buttons are large and inconvenient, and in the future, I require to recreate this code with more materials, therefore a drop down menu is more ideal. Here is the original code:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-large" id="js-material-btn-1">Gold</div>
<div class="btn-large" id="js-material-btn-2">Silver</div>
```

JS:

```
 $( "#js-material-btn-1" ).bind( "click", function(){
   lapi.applyMaterialToMeshByName( "Gold 1", "Group28884");
 }); 
 $( "#js-material-btn-2" ).bind( "click", function(){
   lapi.applyMaterialToMeshByName( "Silver 1", "Group28884");
 });
```

Comment: change `( "Silver 1", "Group28884")` to `( $(this).val(), "Group28884")` also, change your value to say "Silver 1" as it seems that is what your after.

Comment: I just tried this and it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hardcoded "Silver 1" as the option you're submitting.

Where would you expect to get "Gold 1" from? I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Dementic suggested the right answer, here's what it would look like.

For example:

```
<option value="Silver 1" id="silver">Silver</option>
<option value="Gold 1 " id="brass">Brass</option>
```

and your js:

```
$( "#js-mat-sel > select" ).bind( "change", function matchange(){
    lapi.applyMaterialToMeshByName( $(this).val(), "Group28884");
 });
```

Note the option value contains the actual value you're sending.

**EDIT:** You're using .val() on a div, but that can only be used on inputs/form elements (ie the select element). You should modify the change event to be bound to the select element, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6YBpp/

You can also change the selector to select the 'select' child element of that div, which I updated the answer to show... either way the scope is incorrect

Comment: Gold 1 is one of the called upon values from the Lagoa API that is being used.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a jsfiddle with some working code so that this can be tested... 

I don't know about the API, but unless the API can take either 'silver 1' or 'group28884' and convert those parameters into 'gold1', then there's no way that should be working. You're applying  the same parameters every time something is selected.

Comment: Yeah, I know the issue with the code I presented, I just didn't know how to make it work with multiple variables instead of a set one. I don't know JS, so I didn't know what I needed to do to make the value change based on the drop down.

For some reason the corrections provided aren't working at all. Currently, the drop down doesn't change anything. I have triple-checked the code to make sure the syntax is correct, and I don't have any errors. I don't know what the problem is at this point.

Is there another method besides $(this).val() to call upon the value selected?